# Disable Firefox event log in console

Tags: firefox, console, mouseevent

As soon as I open Firefox console it starts printing every mouse move or click I do into console. I never enabled such feature, maybe I might have pressed some shortcut since this is a fresh install.

This starts on any website I visit. Even if I try with `Private window` same issue happens, even with all add-ons turned off.

[image: firefox event logging]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F12 > Debugger > Untick LOG

[image]